# eConnect Classes not visible in referenced dll Microsoft\Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.Serialization.dll

Tags: web-services, wcf, service, dynamics-gp

**IV_Suggest_Sales_Setup_HDR(IV00400),IV_Suggest_Sales_Setup_LINE(IV00401)** These are two classes to insert suggested items in Item card
These are two tables related to suggested items in Item card and i found that these are the two econnect classes through  this http://www.profad.com/media/259634/company-data-archive-manual-gp-2013.pdf  link but i am not able to access these IV_Suggest_Sales_Setup_HDR, IV_Suggest_Sales_Setup_LINE  2 classes through econnect reference and when i check Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.Serialization.dll classes i am not able to see those classes in my dll  using object browser and i figured out that these classes are not available inside econnect dll itself.
Can anybody help me how can i enable and add those classes in my econnect reference ?
I am new econnect and GP please help me in resolving this issue
I AM USING GP2013
Thanks 
Sandeep K

Comment: Please, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question so as to make it clear and easy to understand and read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom nodes in .XSD file and generate dll and consume it

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/developingfordynamicsgp/2010/12/02/creating-a-custom-serialization-assembly-for-econnect-for-microsoft-dynamics-gp-2010/

https://community.dynamics.com/gp/f/32/t/206876